# How to add a button to close this video player code

Tags: html, css, html5-video

[Video example](https://testeblogdetestes.blogspot.com/2019/07/blog-post_60.html)

My code:

```html
<style type="text/css">       
    #Video1
     {
     position:;
     top: 50px;
     left:10px;        
     width:500px;       
     border:0px solid blue;
     display:block;
     z-index:99;
     }
        
        
   #Video2
     {

     position:absolute;
     top: 70px;
     left:120px;
     width:200px;
     border:0px solid red;        
     z-index:100;
     
    }
</style>
</head>
    <body>        
     

<center> <video id="Video1" controls loop autoplay >
<source src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/orPU3x-H8_xqOJ-CoVw-fyBKqdngFrL7g3YJD6j4tUbZO5mLMC15cn
5aKQBd0kIhNvt3NKomiPU9EHv_tKYvfNKwJ1-hvmKEX-ldqCmwNeq_VtQYVeMEmylhFAq9vND_EhHbYO5iYg=m18" type="video/mp4" />        
       </video></center>
       
      


<center><video id="Video2" muted autoplay controls  button >

           
<source src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/orPU3x-H8_xqOJ-CoVw-fyBKqdngFrL7g3YJD6j4tUbZO5mLMC15cn
5aKQBd0kIhNvt3NKomiPU9EHv_tKYvfNKwJ1-hvmKEX-ldqCmwNeq_VtQYVeMEmylhFAq9vND_EhHbYO5iYg=m18"  type="video/mp4" />

    HTML5 Video not supported
       
      </video></center>
```

[Insert a button to close the small video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LMio.png)

I cannot implement this button. Perhaps I am not using the correct HTML, or my CSS is wrong.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a close button? There is currently a pause button?

Comment: ONE BUTTON TO HIDE THE LESS VIDEO, LET IT INVISIBLE, I USE IT TAG video + button.close
DID NOT WORK

Comment: HOW TO IMPLEMENT BUTTON CLOSE ELEMENT IN CSS CODE # Video2?

Comment: Hi there, can you please add a little bit more information explaining your code sample, and about what you're trying to do, it's current behavior, and the things you've tried? That will help attract the people who can answer your question, and give them some background so that they know what you're trying to accomplish. Here's a link that describes how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Thanks and enjoy the site

Comment: Have you actually tried to put a close button? This HTML/CSS snippet does not contain any sort of close button. Please be advised that you must try to implement this feature, as we can not be writing the code for you. Please update your question to include your code that you tried for the close button for further debugging help.

Comment: EXAMPLE:  https://i.imgur.com/L1hvB0k.png

Comment: Please refrain from all-caps shouting on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: none;` to close the video.
See more about display property on: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Html:

```
<button id="CloseButton" onclick="closeVideo()" > x </button>
```

JS:

```
closeVideo = function() {
     document.getElementById('Video2').style.display ='none';
     document.getElementById('CloseButton').style.display ='none';
}
```

The Snippet you provided with the button working:

```html
<head>
    <style type="text/css">       
       #Video1 {
       position:;
       top: 50px;
       left:10px;        
       width:500px;       
       border:0px solid blue;
       display:block;
       z-index:99;
    }
             
    #Video2 {
       position:absolute;
       top: 70px;
       left:120px;
       width:200px;
       border:0px solid red;        
       z-index:100;
    }

    #CloseButton {
       color:red;
       position:absolute;
       top:80px;
       left:310px;
       width:20px;
       height:20px;
       z-index:200;
       text-align:center;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
      closeVideo = function() {
          document.getElementById('Video2').style.display ='none';
          document.getElementById('CloseButton').style.display ='none';
      }
  </script>

</head>

<body>              
    <button id="CloseButton" onclick="closeVideo()" > x </button>
    <center>
        <video id="Video1" controls loop autoplay >
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />        
        </video>
    </center>
       
    <center>
        <video id="Video2" muted autoplay controls  button >
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />

        HTML5 Video not supported
        </video>
    </center>
</body>
```